# Realm Android Cannot resolve symbol 'SyncUser'

Tags: java, android, synchronization, realm

I get a "Cannot resolve symbol" error whenever I try to import the classes below.

```
io.realm.ObjectServerError;
io.realm.SyncCredentials;
io.realm.SyncUser;
```

but not when I try to  import

```
io.realm.RealmQuery;
io.realm.RealmResults;
io.realm.Realm;
```

I have added

```
realm{
    syncEnabled = true
}
```

in my app build.gradle but it still shows the same error.

Here is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

realm{
    syncEnabled = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ktoon"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Here is my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a number of breaking changes to the API in 10.0.0. Among them, SyncUser was renamed to `io.realm.mongodb.User`. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1000-2020-10-15 for the full list